# Not able to create Merchant Account on Sandbox

Tags: android-pay

I am trying to implement the google wallet for digital goods in my application. Here is the link : 
https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/

I have created the buyer account with the testing card as told in api tutorial , but not able to create the merchant account to get the merchant id and secret key to test at local. I am just stuck . I have seen this issue has been faced by many people but no specific answer what is causing the issue or the solution. When I am filling the form , check the link below 
https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/merchant/signup.html?hl=en_US
When I click on complete signup button it just shows me a preloader forever, I tried with mozilla , chrome and IE.

It might not be the correct place to ask but did anybody has face same issue and did it resolve ?
Is it something to do with google checkout retiring?

Comment: What happens when you go to https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/merchant/settings.html?

Comment: When I submit the form it just load forever and nothing happens.

Comment: Link worked in Mavericks Safari